# Trying to select two elements with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I'm trying to show only the voorgerechten and hoofdgerechten. At the moment I'm outputting this:

[image]

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="menuFromattributeToElement.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
<menu>
  <voorgerechten>
    <gerecht id="1" prijs="3.95">Groene salade</gerecht>
    <gerecht id="2" prijs="4.35">Tomatensoep</gerecht>
    <gerecht id="3" prijs="9.95">Carpaccio</gerecht>
  </voorgerechten>
  <hoofdgerechten>
    <gerecht id="4" prijs="19.95">Gegrilde ossehaas</gerecht>
    <gerecht id="5" prijs="15.95">Linguini al Pesto</gerecht>
    <gerecht id="6" prijs="18.95">Gepocheerde zalm</gerecht>
  </hoofdgerechten>
  <desserts>
    <gerecht id="7" prijs="5.95">Dame Blanche</gerecht>
    <gerecht id="8" prijs="7.45">Banana Split</gerecht>
  </desserts>
</menu>
```

And here is the xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <body>
     <table border="1px">
       <tr>
         <td colspan="6" align="center">
             <h2> Gerechten</h2>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>Naam</th>
         <th>Prijs</th>
         <th>ID</th> 
       </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="//gerecht">
         <tr>
           <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
           </td>
           <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="translate(@prijs, '.', ',')"/>
           </td>
           <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
           </td> 
         </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
   </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the xslt file I have already tried to replace:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//gerecht">
```

with this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//menu/voorgerechten/gerecht or //menu/hoofdgerechten/gerecht">
```

So that it only outputs gerecht that live inside a voorgerechten or hoofdgerecht. But unfortunately my code doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close.  You don't want `or`, you want `|`

```
<xsl:for-each select="/menu/voorgerechten/gerecht | /menu/hoofdgerechten/gerecht">
```

The reason for this: `or` is a logical operator, `|` is the union operator.  When you use `or`, you're trying to make your `select` work on a boolean (`true` or `false`), which doesn't really make sense.  When you use the union operator, you're now working on a union of nodesets, which is what the `select` is looking for.  Also, you don't need the `//` at the beginning, there should only ever be one `<menu>` element since it's the root element.

You might want to consider refactoring your for-each as a template though, or a couple templates - it would make it easier to later change one or the other of your types, or to add in others.  But `for-each` will work just fine here, so that's up to you.

Here's the XSLTransform:
http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFx

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ah is the 'or' the same as the 'exclusive or' in XSLT? If so, then I have understood you.

Comment: The `or` is just a logical operator, it returns a boolean.  i.e. `test='true or false'` would return true, `test='false or false'` would return false

Comment: Yes I have understood that. But I only don't really understand the "|" union operator. Is it the same as the union operator from SQL? If so, then I did understood it.

Comment: Yes, sort of like UNION ALL in SQL.  It gives you a union or two node sets into a single node set.